# Changing Raster Resolution to match other Raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, resampling

I have a raster layer of 0.125 degree resolution and another raster layer of 0.0833 degree resolution. Both the raster layers are to be overlapped. So, I want to change the resolution of 0.0833 resolution raster to 0.125 resolution such that the pixels exactly overlap over each other i.e. corresponding pixels signify the same point on the map. 
P.S.- The 0.125 resolution map is exactly as it should be and is not to be changed.

I tried Gdalwarp simply to change the resolution to 0.125 but the pixels are not overlapping. Any help!!

Comment: GDAL_Translate should do it for you http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html. Assuming both rasters are in the same coordinate system *and* have the same datum. Use the option -tr xres yres where xres and yres are 0.125. Setting the origin with -a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry to match the existing eighth degree raster; I have not used this option so there's a bit of assumption here. You might want to define the resampling method based on *what* your raster is: classified data should be nearest or mode, though continuous data bilinear or cubic works fine for me.

Comment: Using -tap for target aligned pixels together with -tr is often enough for matching.

Comment: @michael It says, -tr and -a_ullr can't be used together